# Terraform: How to deploy in minikube local with .tf script? Any helloworld examples?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, minikube

I am looking for an example helloworld **non-java webservice**,  and a **terraform script** that deploys 2 instances in **local minikube** . Also a way of automatic invoking to check if the service is loadbalanced

Is there any github projects that I can use ?

Does terraform support laptop minikube?

Comment: Someone voted to close, why? No mechanism for them to add justification to close?